# Work with Excel file using Sharepoint document library with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I downloaded and customized this project [asp mvc todo sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-todo-rest-sample). this is working fine without any issue with onedrive excel files/items. but i have to do this using office 365 sharepoint online only. 
i am able to get file id using service point as follows:

```
var serviceEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/items";
```

But I am not sure how should I define workbook end point URL with Sharepoint to update/manipulate same excel file data. Current workbook end point URL as follows (which is not working):

```
var workbookEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/items/" + fileId + "/workbook";
```

My complete method to update cell value in excel file on Sharepoint as follows:

```
public static async Task UpdateExcelCellValue_Sharepoint(string accessToken, string cellAddress, string val)
    {
        string worksheetName = "Parameters";
        var serviceEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/items";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var filesResponse = await client.GetAsync(serviceEndpoint + "?$select=name,id");
        if (filesResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var filesContent = await filesResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject parsedResult = JObject.Parse(filesContent);
            foreach (JObject file in parsedResult["value"])
            {
                var name = (string)file["id"];
                if (name.Contains("173"))
                {
                    fileId = (string)file["id"];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle failed response
        }
        //Set up workbook and worksheet endpoints
        var workbookEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/items/" + fileId + "/workbook";
        var worksheetsEndpoint = workbookEndpoint + "/worksheets";
        var patchMethod = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var summaryTableRowJson = "{" +
                "'values': '" + val + ".csv'" +
            "}";
        var colNamePatchBody = new StringContent(summaryTableRowJson);
        colNamePatchBody.Headers.Clear();
        colNamePatchBody.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var colNameRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(patchMethod, worksheetsEndpoint +
            "('" + worksheetName + "')/range(address='Parameters!B2')")
        { Content = colNamePatchBody };
        var colNameResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(colNameRequestMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work now. For example, here's a path that does work:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/lists/{id}/drive/root:/Book.xlsx:/workbook`. This is one of the possibilities.

You can always try replacing path with ID to see if that works (both should work actually).

Comment: could you please guide {id} refers to? my serviceendpoint is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/mydomain.sharepoint.com:/foa/bd:/lists/Budget/items

i can also add snip of sharepoint lib structure if you need? but i tired this way. still getting error or i might not able to make correct path.

Comment: Id is the same property you [get](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get.md) drive item on. If you just know the parent folder, you can [list](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children.md) the folder content and get the Id of the file.

Comment: now i am able to reach document which are under root site docuemnts library but when i modify url to reach  under root/subsite/subsite on graph api explorer. still no success. any reference to navigate under subsites?

Comment: Do you mind sending sending screen shot of the URL where the file is located? Feel free to email directly at suramam @ microsoft

Comment: I sent you an email with screenshot.